# how to remove youtube title from iframe?

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

We are developing a portal for our client in Angular 7. 
In that portal we are using swiper plugin to display slides in our page. 
swiper plugin link - http://idangero.us/swiper/

In that slider - we are displaying YouTube video via `iframe`. I want to remove YouTube title from `iframe`. So kindly give solution for same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you will be able to remove the title. According to [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018)
article the parameter that was used to hide the title is *deprecated*. Here is the snippet of the article that states this will be in effect as of September 25, 2018:

*The showinfo parameter, which indicates whether the player should display information like the video title and uploader before the video starts playing, is also being deprecated. Following the change, the channel avatar and video title will always display before playback begins, when playback is paused, and when playback ends. The avatar being displayed is new behavior that will be consistent across all embedded players.*

If you want a video without a title, you can always try Vimeo.

Comment: Is there any other way to do that for YouTube video?

Comment: Unfortunately not for YouTube, no.

Comment: I have the opposite problem, the title is now not displayed.